# How do I insert an m3u playlist on a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, media, playlist

I want to play a m3u file songs in a player

I am using the following player, but it's not playing:

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab# Version=5,1,52,701" STANDBY="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" width="280" height="46">
    <param name="fileName" value="songs/songs/1990/1990/enthiran/test1.m3u">
    <param name="animationatStart" value="true">
    <param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
    <param name="autoStart" value="true">
    <param name="showControls" value="true">
    <param name="Volume" value="-300">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="songs/1990/1990/enthiran/001Saravanapoigayel.mp3" name="MediaPlayer1" width=280 height=46 autostart=1 showcontrols=1 volume=-300>
</OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 3):

This example code will be useful to you. Check it.

Add your playlist location like `<param name="fileName" value="YOUR PLAYLIST LOCATION URL">`

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab# Version=5,1,52,701" STANDBY="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" width="280" height="46">
    <param name="fileName" value="http://www.domain.com/music/music.m3u"> 
    <param name="animationatStart" value="true">
    <param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
    <param name="autoStart" value="true">
    <param name="showControls" value="true">
    <param name="Volume" value="-300">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="http://www.domain.com/music/music.m3u" name="MediaPlayer1" width=280 height=46 autostart=1 showcontrols=1 volume=-300>
    </OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 2):

**m3u** is not a music format, it is playlist.
Search for some players, that supports playlist, f.e. [this one](http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/).