# Live Flash Player for m3u File

Tags: html, wordpress, flash, live, internet-radio

I'm searching for a Flash Player that can play a m3u File. I can open m3u file with Windows Media Player, but I want to embed into my blog.

I have the URL of m3u file. It is used for a radio station.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players) does this. You just have to pass it correct parameter.

Here is an exact snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871647/141200

If your wordpress, their Wordpress plugin works great: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/

Shortcode snippet: [jwplayer height="24" file="http://domain/podcasts/playlist.m3u"]